# Iterate over every value in data frame and compare it with a mean within a column, return a data frame

Tags: r, function, datetime, data-manipulation

I am struggling with writing a function that would iterate over every value in a data frame and return a data frame only with values that don't meet a threshold but with the same column names.

Here is a dataframe:

```
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
bonus <- c(350, 400, 170)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-2','2010-11-3'))
df <- data.frame(startdate, salary, bonus)
```

Here is my function:

```
def2 <- function(x, column){
  d = NULL
  for (row in 1:nrow(x)) {
  val <- x[row,column]
  dat <- x[row, "startdate"]
  m <- mean(x[,column])
  y <- (as.Date(dat)-2)
    if (val < m) {
      if (val < y) {
        print('Number is too low')
      } else {
        susp_date = paste(dat)
        value = paste(val)
        d = rbind(d, data.frame(susp_date, value))
      }
    } else {
      next
    }
  }
  return (d)
}
```

So basically, I get a more or less desired output: I can see values that are less than a mean within a column. Here is an output I get:

```
susp_date value
1 2010-11-01 21000
2 2010-11-02 23400
```

But I want to save the names and the order of columns as in input data frame and have this view for all the columns and not just for one.

My dream is that I get a data frame as an output with the same columns as an original one but values are replaced with 1 if the value is lower than a mean within a column AND less than a value that corresponds to a value (start date - 2 days) and 0 if non of these conditions are held:

```
   startdate salary bonus
1 2010-11-01  1       0
2 2010-11-02  1       0
3 2010-11-03  0       1
```

I have tried different methods including copying a data frame and then filling it dynamically; using lapply (in my case several conditions should be held) and mix of them but no success..
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What is the purpose of *start_date*?

Comment: *"My dream is that I get a data frame as an output with the same columns as an original one but values are replaced with 1 if the value is lower than a mean within a group and 0 if a value is greater than a mean...*" then you should probably make an example where there is a grouping column.

Comment: @Parfait I also have a condition to check every value with a one from the same column -2 days. So basically I have two conditions: to compare with a mean within a column and with a value that corresponds to a retrospective date.

Comment: @Gregor to compare with a mean within each column, will edit it now, thanks

Comment: A couple notes on your code: 1) don't use `paste(val)` and `paste(dat)`, it will convert to `character` class. Especially the `val`, you probably want to keep as a number. 2) If possible, it's almost always better to iterate over columns than over rows. 3) Try not to `rbind` or `cbind` things in loops - it is very much more efficient to initialize your output to the correct size and "fill in the blanks" than to "grow" an object at every iteration. 4) The `colMeans` function is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what you want. This post will be adjusted if it is not.

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(as.numeric(. < mean(.))))

  startdate salary bonus
1 2010-11-01      1     0
2 2010-11-02      1     0
3 2010-11-03      0     1
```

Comment: Worth noting that this can easily be combined with `group_by` to meet OP's "dream".

Comment: Yes of course. If there are groups, then `group_by` will be needed. The OP's question didn't give information on groups unfortunately. It's a bit vague really.

Comment: Also, worth nothing the OP's explanation of retrospective date condition.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess thank you, always forget about how dplyr is powerful. But I have just one more condition with a value of a retrospective date that's why was thinking of writing a function

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that doesn't use any libraries. All you have to do is use `sapply`  and `ifelse` in your function. `Sapply` iterates over each elememt in the column. Edited to include both conditions. :

```
def2<-function(x){
  m<-mean(x, na.rm=T)
  sapply(x, function(y){
    ifelse(y>m,1,0)
  })
}

# Both conditions (assumes date is ordered (ascending) and doesn't have any duplicates!)
def2<-function(w,x){
  m<-mean(x, na.rm=T)
  sapply(seq_along(x), function(y){
    n<-w[y]-2
    o<-df$salary[df$startdate==n]
    ifelse((x[y]>m & x[y]>o) ,1,0)
  })
}

# Applying the function
df$bonus<-def2(x=df$salary,w=df$startdate)
```